# Change values in column compared to other column with pandas in Python

Tags: pandas

I'm a beginner with Python and pandas, hope anyone can help!

I have a csv file with two columns, one that tells the date (15-02-88) and the number of damage free years of owning a car (dfy). Since you have to be 18 in order to obtain a license, the number of damage free years can therefore never be more than your age - dfy. So for instance, when someone is born in 88, the damage free years cannot be higher than 10.

```
birthdate  dfy
15-02-88   20
28-09-92    2
08-03-52   28
```

I want to make sure that I change all the values in the dfy column, so that the impossible ones are changed to a value that are possible.

So far I have this:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta, date


df = pd.read_csv('Path')


for row in df.iterrows():
    years_over_18 = (datetime.date.today())
    years_over_18 = jaren_over_18 - row[1]['birthdate'] -  row[1]['birthdate']) - timedelta(days = 365.25 * 18) 
    damage_free_years = timedelta(days = row[1]['dfy'] * 18) 
    print (years_over_18 >= damage_free_years)

df = pd.read_csv('Path')
over_18 = []

for row in df.iterrows():
    years_over_18 = datetime.date.today() -  row[1]['birthdate'] timedelta(days = 365.25 * 18) 
    damage_free_years = timedelta(days = row[1]['dfy'] * 18) 
    over_18.append(jaren_over_18 >= damagefreeyears)

df['over_18'] = over_18
```

However, I'm really struggling with what I can/ can't do with pandas and how to make it work. If anyone has suggestions or could help, I'd really appreciate it!

Reproducible example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame({"birtdate":["15-02-88", "28-09-92", "08-03-52"], "dfy":[20,2,28]})
```

Comment: Firstly you might want to try df.birthdate.iloc[1].type to check that what you are reading in is coming as a datetime and not a string (you're example is giving dates as strings)

Comment: And secondly I would investigate numpy.where, but I don't have meaningful experience with dates so there may well be a better way

Comment: pd.to_datetime(date) is how you would convert strings to datetime